# K8S: Unable to connect to MinIO Service through my Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to setup an Ingress to talk to MinIO on my cluster.

My MinIO service is called `storage`, and exposes port 9000:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: storage
  name: storage
  namespace: abc
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "http-9000"
    protocol: TCP
    port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: storage
```

And my Ingress is configured like so:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myingress
  namespace: abc
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: storage
    servicePort: http-9000
```

Yet its not responding to the health-checks, and instead my Ingress is redirecting me to a different service (which is actually listening on port 80). How do I get the ingress to redirect me to my `storage` service on 9000?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the config was fine, it was just taking ages to propagate :D